# How to Print an alert on Scroll in any specific Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to print an alert when user Scroll the header, basically i want to set header Display to none after certain area has been scrolled. Right now i want to print an alert when user reach to the content area.

I have written the following code, Its not working correctly. Kindly check it and guide me.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".container").scroll(function () {
        alert("Scrolled!");
    });
});
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="text">This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text This is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random TextThis is Random Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to happen with the scrollbar

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var offset = $(".container").offset().top;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
        alert("Scrolled!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a small change in your code.

```
$(".container").bind('mouseover', function() {
            alert("Scrolled!");
            });

    });
```

Rest will be same.

Comment: but when i use scroll bar to go down it does generate any `alert()`

Comment: It will work whenever you will enter into the div container. That means your mouse over the div.